# Poblem with Query to Get Diference

Tags: mysql, payment, relation, invoices

I am using this query to show Saldo column With Invoices and Payments Values.
Works Good but if i dont have an invoice but i have a payment, i can see It until i add an invoice.
How can i correct It?

```
select B.razonsocial as Empresa, Facturas , 
IFNULL(pay,0) as Pagos, (Facturas - IFNULL(pay,0)) Saldo 
FROM (select TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor, TblProveedores.razonsocial, 
SUM(case when TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'A' or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante='B' or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'NDA' or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'NDB'  or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'C'  or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'NDC' or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'X' then TblFacturasCompras.total else -TblFacturasCompras.total end)  as Facturas 
from TblFacturasCompras left join TblProveedores on TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id group by TblProveedores.id) A 
LEFT JOIN (select TblProveedores.id, TblProveedores.razonsocial, SUM(TblRecibosCompras.total) as Pay from 
TblProveedores left join TblRecibosCompras on TblRecibosCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id  group by TblProveedores.id) B ON A.id_proveedor = B.id 
where B.razonsocial <> '' order by B.razonsocial Asc
```

Comment: Please add minimum sample data showing the case in which your query is not working. Also share expected output and the output your query is getting!

Comment: For example, i Have Table Invoices and Table Payments, The relationship is Made by Supplier in both tables. I must check how much payments have, and how mach invoices and show the Diferences, If i have one registry on each table from same supplier, works good, but if i have just a payment, and no invoices, i cant get a result.

Comment: i have solved with Right Join

Answer (score 0):

you are using a column involved in left join in a where condition

```
 where B.razonsocial <> ''
```

this work as an inner join  try add the condition to the related  on clause

```
select B.razonsocial as Empresa
    , Facturas
    , IFNULL(pay,0) as Pagos
    , (Facturas - IFNULL(pay,0)) Saldo 
    FROM (  
        select TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor
            , TblProveedores.razonsocial
            , SUM(case when 
                        TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'A' 
                        or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante='B' 
                        or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'NDA' 
                        or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'NDB'  
                        or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'C'  
                        or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'NDC' 
                        or TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante = 'X' 
                    then TblFacturasCompras.total 
                    else -TblFacturasCompras.total end)  as Facturas 
        from TblFacturasCompras 
        left join TblProveedores on TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id 
        group by TblProveedores.id
    ) A 
    LEFT JOIN (
        select TblProveedores.id
            , TblProveedores.razonsocial
            , SUM(TblRecibosCompras.total) as Pay 
        from TblProveedores 
        left join TblRecibosCompras on TblRecibosCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id  
        group by TblProveedores.id
    ) B ON A.id_proveedor = B.id and  B.razonsocial <> '' 
    order by B.razonsocial Asc
```

and a suggestion you could use a IN clause instead of several OR clause

```
select B.razonsocial as Empresa
    , Facturas
    , IFNULL(pay,0) as Pagos
    , (Facturas - IFNULL(pay,0)) Saldo 
    FROM (  
        select TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor
            , TblProveedores.razonsocial
            , SUM(case when 
                  TblFacturasCompras.tipocomprobante IN ('A','B','NDA','NDB','C','NDC','X') 
                    then TblFacturasCompras.total 
                    else -TblFacturasCompras.total end)  as Facturas 
        from TblFacturasCompras 
        left join TblProveedores on TblFacturasCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id 
        group by TblProveedores.id
    ) A 
    LEFT JOIN (
        select TblProveedores.id
            , TblProveedores.razonsocial
            , SUM(TblRecibosCompras.total) as Pay 
        from TblProveedores 
        left join TblRecibosCompras on TblRecibosCompras.id_proveedor = TblProveedores.id  
        group by TblProveedores.id
    ) B ON A.id_proveedor = B.id and  B.razonsocial <> '' 
    order by B.razonsocial Asc
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, i think my problem is here: ON A.id_proveedor = B.id, Because A.id_proveedor will never be > 0 because the invoice didnt exists.

Comment: hi have tried your codes but didnt work. i got the same results.

Comment: You comment is not clear  .. you are saying that you have not and id in the from table and want join with a left table  .. explain better .then  a proper data sample , you actualt result  and the expected result are useful

Comment: For example, i Have Table Invoices and Table Payments, The relationship is Made by Supplier in both tables. I must check how much payments have, and how mach invoices and show the Diferences, If i have one registry on each table from same supplier, works good, but if i have just a payment, and no invoices, i cant get a result.

Comment: Was Solved With Right Join. Thanks.